# What is the meaning of line ' trainX = loaded[16:].reshape((602, 256, 256, 1)).astype(np.float32)'?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with capsule networks. [Here](https://github.com/naturomics/CapsNet-Tensorflow) is the code I am referencing.

I am using own dataset of training images 602. The dimension of image is `256x256` grayscale images.

I am not getting meaning of specific line in main file

`trainX = loaded[16:].reshape((602, 256, 256, 1)).astype(np.float32)`

Because of this,I am getting error

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12058624 into shape (602,256,256,1)`

Can anyone help me getting out of this. Thank you.

Comment: 602*256*256*1 != 12058624

Comment: @Red Floyd, so array size is 12058640. Should I change the value of dimension 256x256 according to that?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing (602,256,256,1) by (-1,256,256,1), the ValueError is resolved. Here, -1 represents dimension value accordingly that calculated automatically.

The reference is here https://github.com/naturomics/CapsNet-Tensorflow/issues/69.